# C# How to declare variables with specific index?

Tags: c#, variables, declaration

Generally, we declare variable with specific name.
    int x=1;
    int life2 = 100;

But what if i want to declare group of variable with some specific index like this
    x1 , x2, x3, ... x(n)
Instead of manually brute force declare
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,..... x(n);
How can i achieve this by not using array or list?

I uncertainly remember this can achieve by using loop and some special syntax like

```
for(int f1=0;f1<10;f1++)
{
 string temp = ""+f1;
 int x+temp; //something
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: And why not use an array or list?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this in C#, and I can't see why you would want to, rather than just indexing an array or a list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) whose members can be added and removed at run time.

For example:

```
dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ((IDictionary<string, object>) expandoObject)["x" + i] = i;
}

Console.WriteLine(expandoObject.x1);  //Will write 1
Console.WriteLine(expandoObject.x2);  //Will write 2
Console.WriteLine(expandoObject.x50); //Will write 50
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this syntax does not work in C#.  You will need to use an array or a list.